# why is the li element calculate the height when anchor is inline element

Tags: html, css

I have received an answer from you that says the following. "Without display:block, the anchor(a) element are treated as display:inline. As such, when calculating the size of their parents(height is default to auto), the padding of the anchor(a) element is omitted, while it is included in cases of display:block."

This sound correct but I can't understand why is the li including the size of the padding top and padding bottom of the anchor element when this element is inline element.
I mean according to the previous answer from you should the padding-top and padding:bottom of the anchor element be omitted when the anchor element is in inline element as it is in this markup becuse display:block is comment out.

This anchor element has two parents in a way. The li element is a direct parent to anchor element and ul is a parent to the li element and ul is an ancester to the  anchor element.

If I run the markup the background of the li element is higher because of the padding top and padding bottom of 40px.
When the height of the ul is being calculated then it does not include the padding-top and padding-bottom of the anchor element.

Here is the complete markup and style

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

```
   body
   {
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:small;
      width:820px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
   }

   #nav
   {
       float:left;
       width:100%;
       margin:0;
       padding:10px 0 0 46px;
       list-style:none;
       background:#FFCB2D;
   }

   #nav li
   {
      float:left;
      margin:0 1px 0 0;
      font-family:"Lucida Grande", "sans-serif";
      font-size:90%;
      background:red;
   }

   #nav a
   {
       /*display:block;*/
       margin:0;
       padding:10px 8px;
       color:#333;
       text-decoration:none;
       border:1px solid #9B8748;
       border-bottom:none;
       background:#F9E9A9;
   }

    #nav a:hover
   {
       color:#333;
       padding-bottom:5px;
       border-color:#727377;
      background:#fff;
   }
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Chapter 3</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="t-intro"><a href="/">Introduction</a></li>
  <li id="t-about"><a href="about.html">About Lance</a></li>
  <li id="t-news"><a href="news.html">News &amp; Events</a></li>
  <li id="t-sponsors"><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
</ul> 
</body>
```

//Tony

Comment: The answer you've read is wrong. Padding is always taken into account, inline element or block. *Margin* is only taken into account for block elements.

Comment: Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/B52sG/ (note how `padding-bottom: 5px;` does not behave the way you probably intended)

Comment: You can read http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/ where they say While padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content which is t

Comment: Because adjacent `padding` in inline elements is collapsed much like adjacent `margin` is collapsed for block elements. What counts for the placement of inline elements is the height of the *line box*, which is defined by `font-size` and `line-height`. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/Ym9yy/. You also might want to play with `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have received an answer from you that says the following. "Without display:block, the anchor(a) element are treated as display:inline. As such, when calculating the size of their parents(height is default to auto), the padding of the anchor(a) element is omitted, while it is included in cases of display:block."

It is true. Your `<li>`-s height is based on the line-height. You see the padding because [overflow defaults to visible](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow). If you set

```
li {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

then the top and bottom padding disappears.

[Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced) on inline non-replaced element's height:

> The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when calculating the height of the line box.

[Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block) on calculating block's height:

> Only children in the normal flow are taken into account (i.e., floating boxes and absolutely positioned boxes are ignored, and relatively positioned boxes are considered without their offset). Note that the child box may be an anonymous block box.

So your ul gets height: 0. There are several solutions for this problem, see them on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).